# writing java code to find max&min. getting stuck on if there's only one input

Tags: java, input, dialog, max, min

Posted below is what I have so far. It works, however if there's only one answer, one of the outputs sets to zero. Does anyone have an idea for getting around this? My professor specifically asked that we make sure to write the code to include this situation.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input;
    int number;
    int option;
    int min;
    int max;

    option = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;        
    max = 0;
    min = 0;
    while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number: ");
    number = Integer.parseInt(input);

    if(number < max)
        min = number;
    else if(number > min)
        max = number;

    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
    (null, "Would you like to enter another number?");

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The smallest number entered is "
    + min + ". The largest number entered is " + max + ".");
}
```

Comment: Use an if statement to check if there's only one answer and then print a different output.

Comment: How can I check if there's only one input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial values are wrong :

```
max = 0;
min = 0;
```

If you enter only negative numbers, all will be smaller than the original `max`, so `max` will remain 0. Similarly, if you enter only positive numbers, all will be larger than the original `min`, so `min` will remain 0.

Change them to :

```
max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Edit :

You got the condition backwards.

Change :

```
if(number < max)
    min = number;
else if(number > min)
    max = number;
```

to

```
if(number > max)
    max = number;
if(number < min)
    min = number;
```

Comment: When I switch those values to what you suggested, it returns values of 2147483647 and -2147483647

Comment: @Terra I just noticed your conditions are wrong. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not even work with 2 or more inputs (just test with same number two or more times). To fix it just **remove the "else"** leaving two separate if statements. Also you should set min max as Eran states in his answer:

```
max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Edit:
Sorry there were more errors, the statements should be like this:

```
if(number < min)
    min = number;
if(number > max)
    max = number;
```

Comment: it has been working with 2 or more inputs. If I only enter the same number twice, I get the same error as when I enter only one input, but it doesn't change when I take away the "else" as you've suggested

Comment: You mixed up the conditions as well if(number < max) min = number; should be if (number < min) min = number; same for max.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!!! I have a feeling my text book isn't great. No where in it do I see the Integer.MIN/MAX_VALUE; or using separate if statements as opposed to if else statements. Any online resource suggestions besides video tutorials?

Comment: @Terra Don't know the good books today (started with it over 15 years back), but you might try these: http://www.mkyong.com/featured/top-5-free-java-ebooks/ . Also you might want to accept the answer if it solved your problem.